# Evaluating Sums Algebraically or Combinatorially

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider

(1) $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{k-n}$$

(2) $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{(n+k+1)!}$$

These sums appear too difficult (in my mind) to evaluate combinatorially.  What are some good methods to attack these problems algebraically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $(1)$, consider the binomial theorem. First write $2^{k-n}$ as $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}$. Then:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} 2^{k-n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k} 1^{k} = \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n}$$

[Numerical results](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C15%2C105%2C945%2C10395&language=english&go=Search) suggest that the second sum can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k}\frac{k!}{(n+k+1)!}=\frac{2^{n}}{1*3*\ldots*(2n+1)}=\frac{n!}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm afraid I can't seem to solve the second problem.

Comment: Indeed, I can't see any way to go from there. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D0%29^n+%28binomial%28n%2C+k%29+k!%29%2F%28%281%2Bk%2Bn%29!%29) suggests an argument involving the gamma function (although the results are rational, which means it could be a coincidence). From the numerical results $n=1,2,3\ldots$ the numerators are powers of $2$, and the denominators appear to be of the form $1*3*5*...*(2*n-1)$, (see the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C15%2C105%2C945%2C10395&language=english&go=Search))

Comment: Hmm, I will have to think about it further.  The result, if correct, is nice and simple but I am not sure how to obtain it algebraically.

Answer (score 7):

A combinatorial argument for (1) isn’t too hard. First rewrite the sum:

$$\sum_k\binom{n}k2^{k-n}=2^{-n}\sum_k\binom{n}k2^k\;.$$

Now $\binom{n}k2^k$ is the number of ways of choosing a $k$-subset $S$ of $[n]$ and then a subset $T$ of $S$, so $\sum_k\binom{n}k2^k$ is the number of ways of splitting $[n]$ into three subsets. This is clearly $3^n$, so the original expression is $\left(\frac32\right)^n$.

I don’t at the moment see a useful combinatorial interpretation of the second summation, but I can evaluate it. If

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\frac{k!}{(n+k+1)!}\;,$$

then we have the following data:

$$\begin{array}{c|r}
n&f(n)\\ \hline
0&1=\frac{2^0}{1!!}\\
1&\frac12+\frac16=\frac23=\frac{2^1}{3!!}\\
2&\frac16+\frac2{24}+\frac2{120}=\frac4{15}=\frac{2^2}{5!!}\\
3&\frac1{24}+\frac1{40}+\frac1{120}+\frac1{840}=\frac8{105}=\frac{2^3}{7!!}\\
4&\frac1{120}+\frac1{180}+\frac1{420}+\frac1{1680}+\frac1{15120}=\frac{16}{945}=\frac{2^4}{9!!}
\end{array}$$

Apparently $f(n)=\dfrac{2^n}{(2n+1)!!}=\dfrac{4^nn!}{(2n+1)!}$. Now

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}f(n)&=\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k\frac{k!}{(n+k+1)!}\\\\
&=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}kk!(2n+1)^{\underline{n-k}}\\\\
&=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^nn^\underline k(2n+1)^{\underline{n-k}}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2n+1)^{\underline{n-k}}}{(n-k)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{n-k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}k\;.
\end{align*}$$

(Here $x^{\underline k}$ is the [falling factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol).) And

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}k=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}k\;,$$

so

$$\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}f(n)=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}k=2^{2n}=4^n\;,$$

and the conjecture that $f(n)=\dfrac{2^n}{(2n+1)!!}=\dfrac{4^nn!}{(2n+1)!}$ is established.

Comment: The combinatorial argument is especially helpful.  Is it really just a game of looking at the data for the second identity?

Comment: @user73041: There may be a cleverer way, but that’s how I discovered the result. Then it took me a little while to find the argument. I suspect that there is a combinatorial argument, but I’ve not found one yet.

Answer (score 6):

The second sum

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{k!}{(n+k+1)!} $$

can be rewritten as

$$\frac{n!}{(2n+1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{n-k} = \frac{2^{2n} n!}{(2n+1)!}$$

expand $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$, cancel the $k!$ and multiply and divide by $(2n+1)!$ and,

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{n-k} = \binom{2n+1}{n} + \binom{2n+1}{n-1} + \dots + \binom{2n+1}{0} =  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2n+1} \binom{2n+1}{k} = 2^{2n}$

Comment: Very clever - how did you decide on that identity in the second line?

Comment: Seeing $(n-k)!(n+k+1)!$ in the denominator, it seems natural to try and get $((n-k) + (n+k+1))!$ in the numerator, which cancels the $k$ out, and we get a nice binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{k-n}=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^k\cdot1^{n-k}=2^{-n}(2+1)^n=(3/2)^n$$

Comment: Much appreciated!  Is the idea usually then to see some relation to a major identity like the binomial theorem, Pascal's Rule, Vandermonde, or otherwise?