# In Pursuit of a Broader Understanding of Complicated Binomial Coefficient Sums

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{(n+k+1)!}$$

The above identity was posted [once before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366752/evaluating-sums-algebraically-or-combinatorially) by me, however, all results were obtained numerically exploring the identity rather than understanding it combinatorially or performing explicit manipulations on it algebraically.  I was hoping by posting again I might be able to entice someone a bit more capable than myself to consider again whether there might be a good combinatorial interpretation for this after all, and whether there are some general guidelines for both arriving at these interpretations, and choosing the proper algebraic manipulations where necessary to see them.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Wilf-Zeilberger (WZ) theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) (expounded in [their book with Petkovsek, *A=B*](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf))?

Comment: I am not unfortunately, so for purposes here it will not be immediately eye-opening.  I will certainly explore it further though.

Comment: It does not seem likely to have a combinatorial interpretation, since the terms are typically non-integral.

Comment: This is good to know as well.  I am not well-read enough yet to know when a sum like this will be able to be interpreted at all.

Comment: @vadim123, it might be possible to "complete" to integers and thus get a combinatorial interpretation. But the simplest way is a factor $(2 n + 1)!$, and I don't see anything useful comming out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{k!}{(n+k+1)!}\;.$$

Then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}f(n)&=\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!\,k!}{k!(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n-k)!(n+k+1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{n-k}\\\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n+1}k\\\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}k\\\\
&=2^{2n}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$f(n)=\frac{4^nn!}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{2^n}{(2n+1)!!}\;.$$